# Javascript refresh webpage every 5s

Tags: javascript

I refrence the JS unlock right click script:

```
javascript:(function() { if(window.addEventListener) window.addEventListener(a, function (e) { for(var n=e.originalTarget; n; n=n.parentNode) n[ona]=null; }, true); window[ona]=null; document[ona]=null; if(document.body) document.body[ona]=null; } R("contextmenu"); R("click"); R("mousedown"); R("mouseup"); R("selectstart");})()
```

when you put the link in the url and enter, you can use right.

---

so I want to make a js link to put in the url and enter, the website will refresh every 5s.

```
javascript:(function() {
function refresh() {
             window.location.reload(true);}
setTimeout(refresh, 5000);
})()
```

but I can't do that, please help. 
because my English too bad, if u don't understand, ask me.

Comment: Every five seconds? Now ***there's*** a user experience for you...

Comment: I want to test, later i want to do next function.

Answer (score 2):

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; URL=http://www.yourdomain.com/yoursite.html">
```

If it has to be in the script use setTimeout like:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, 5000);
```

Comment: method 1. I have try this, this cannot solve the problem, if the website is not myself.
method2. I have chage my script, but it cannot work.
`javascript:(function() { function refresh() { window.location.reload(true); setTimeout(function(){ window.location.reload(1); }, 5000); })()`

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {
    setTimeout("location.reload(true);",timeoutPeriod);
}
//   -->
</script>
```

Comment: A string value for param 1 of setTimeout?  How very 1990s.

Comment: Sorry, this cannot work...
`javascript:(function timedRefresh(timeoutPeriod) {setTimeout("location.reload(true);",5000);})()`